# List view example for a fragment class (getting data from a JSON)

Tags: android, json, listview, android-fragments

Can someone give me a example code on how to use a listview in a fragment class. 
I have a JSON and it has data of some NEWS. I want to display those news in a listview. When you click an item in the listview you'll be directed to a detailed news section.
How can i do this? i already have a adapter class which i used for other activities in my program

LazyAdapter class

```
package com.fortuna.cinemalk.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import com.fg.sinhala.Sihala;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.lazyloading.ImageLoader;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.R;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.BaseElement;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.Film;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.GridElement;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.News;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.Theater;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.util.Element;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<BaseElement> item;

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private int type;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    Context context;

    public LazyAdapter(ArrayList<BaseElement> item, Activity activity, int type) {

        this.item = item;

        this.activity = activity;
        this.type = type;
        this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return item.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View viewCon, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View view = null;
        ListView view1 = null;

        if (Element.LEFT_MENU.getType() == type) {

            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.leftmenu_list_layout, null);

            GridElement gridElement = (GridElement) item.get(position);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.leftmenu_icon);

            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.leftmenu_title);

            title.setText(gridElement.getTitle());

            image.setImageResource(gridElement.getIcon());

        }
        if (Element.MOVIE_LIST.getType() == type) {

            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_list_layout, null);

            Film film = (Film) item.get(position);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

            title.setText(film.getTitle());

            // image.setImageResource(film.getImage());

        }

/*  if (Element.NEWS_LIST.getType() == type) {

            view1 = (ListView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list, null);

            News news = (News) item.get(position);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_image);

            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_title);

            title.setText(news.getTitle());

            // image.setImageResource(film.getImage());

        } */

        if (Element.THEATER_LIST.getType() == type) {

            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.theater_list_layout, null);

            Theater theater = (Theater) item.get(position);

            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.theater_name);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_theater);





        /*  name.setText(theater.getName());

            imageLoader
                    .DisplayImage(theater.getTheaterImage(), activity, image);
        }

        return view;
    }
} */



        //use this to all elements that have sinhala texts  
    Sihala sinhla = new Sihala(activity);

            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), sinhla.font);

            name.setTypeface(typeface);

            name.setText(sinhla.getSinhalaString(theater.getName()));

            imageLoader
                    .DisplayImage(theater.getTheaterImage(), activity, image);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

My attempted NewsFragment class ( Not sure if this is correct)

```
package com.fortuna.cinemalk;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.fortuna.cinemalk.TheaterFragment.BackGround;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.adapter.LazyAdapter;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.BaseElement;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.service.CommonVariable;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.service.JSONServices;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.util.Element;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class NewsFramgment extends Fragment{

    private ListView listview;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<BaseElement> newscolumn;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_fragment,
                container, false);

        activity = this.getActivity();

        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();

        listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);


        /*listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                 int position, long id) {


              android.support.v4.app.Fragment detail = new NewsDetailFragment();
              android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
              fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, detail).addToBackStack("back").commit();
               }
              }); */



            new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }


public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            newscolumn = JSONServices.getNewsDescription();
            return null;
        } 



        @Override
        /* check again */
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            commonVariable.setTheater(newscolumn);

            adapter = new LazyAdapter(newscolumn, activity,Element.NEWS_LIST.getType());

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }


}
```

My JSON service class

```
package com.fortuna.cinemalk.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.graphics.Paint.Join;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.BaseElement;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.Film;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.FilmBanner;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.FilmCategory;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.Home;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.News;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.Theater;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.util.JSONTag;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.util.ServiceURL;

public class JSONServices {

    public static ArrayList<BaseElement> getCategory() {



        ArrayList<BaseElement> catogory = new ArrayList<BaseElement>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(
                    CommonService.readJsonUrl(ServiceURL.CATEGORY_TOPCAT
                            .getUrl()));

            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSONTag.CATEGORY.getTag());
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                FilmCategory filmCategory = new FilmCategory();

                filmCategory.setCatId(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.ID.getTag()));
                filmCategory.setCategory(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.NAME
                        .getTag()));

                catogory.add(filmCategory);

                // news.put(i, newsCategory);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return catogory;

    }

    public static ArrayList<BaseElement> getCategoryById(String id) {

        ArrayList<BaseElement> films = new ArrayList<BaseElement>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(CommonService.readJsonFromUrl(ServiceURL.MOVE_BY_CATEGORY
                            .getUrl() + id));

            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSONTag.MOVIE.getTag());
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                Film film = new Film();

                film.setActorsActress(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.ACTOER_ACTRESS
                        .getTag()));
                film.setComposer(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.COMPOSER.getTag()));
                film.setDescrition(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.DESCRIPTION
                        .getTag()));
                film.setDirecter(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.DIRECTOR.getTag()));
                film.setGenre(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.GENERE.getTag()));
                film.setImage(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.IMAGE_2.getTag()));
                film.setIMDbRating(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.IMDB_RATING
                        .getTag()));
                film.setLength(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.LENGTH.getTag()));
                film.setNewsId(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.ID.getTag()));
                film.setPlot(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.PLOT.getTag()));
                film.setProducer(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.PRODUCER.getTag()));

                films.add(film);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return films;

    }

    public static ArrayList<BaseElement> getNewsDescription() {

        ArrayList<BaseElement> newsitem = new ArrayList<BaseElement>();

        //LinkedHashMap<Integer, BaseElement> news = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, BaseElement>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(
                    CommonService
                            .readJsonFromUrl(ServiceURL.NEWS_CONTENT
                                    .getUrl() ));

            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("news");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                News newsDescription = new News();

                newsDescription.setNewsId(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.ID.getTag()));

                newsDescription.setTitle(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.TITLE.getTag()));

                //newsDescription.setShortDescription(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.SHORTDESCRIPTION.getTag()));

                //newsDescription.setDescrition(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.DESCRIPTION.getTag()));

                newsDescription.setThumbImage(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.THUMBNAIL.getTag()));

                //newsDescription.setImage(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.IMAGE.getTag()));

                //newsDescription.setTrailerImage(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.TRAILER_IMAGE.getTag()));

                //newsDescription.setVideo(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag._VIDEO.getTag()));

                //news.put(i, newsDescription);

                newsitem.add(newsDescription);

}

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }

        return newsitem;

    }




    public static LinkedHashMap<Integer, BaseElement> getHomeContent() {

        LinkedHashMap<Integer, BaseElement> news = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, BaseElement>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(
                    CommonService.readJsonFromUrl(ServiceURL.HOME_CONTENT
                            .getUrl()));

            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("home");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                Home home = new Home();

                JSONArray homeArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("photos");

                LinkedHashMap<Integer, BaseElement> banner = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, BaseElement>();

                for (int j = 0; j < homeArray.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = homeArray.getJSONObject(j);

                    FilmBanner filmBanner = new FilmBanner();

                    filmBanner.setId(jsonObject2.getString(JSONTag.ID.getTag()));
                    filmBanner.setTitle(jsonObject2.getString(JSONTag.TITLE.getTag()));
                    filmBanner.setDescription(jsonObject2.getString(JSONTag.SHORTDESCRIPTION.getTag()));
                    filmBanner.setImage(jsonObject2.getString(JSONTag.IMAGE.getTag()));
                    filmBanner.setThumb(jsonObject2.getString(JSONTag.THUMBNAIL.getTag()));
                    filmBanner.setType(jsonObject2.getString(JSONTag.TYPE.getTag()));

                    banner.put(j, filmBanner);

                }

                home.setCategory(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.CATEGORY.getTag()));
                home.setImages(banner);

                news.put(i, home);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return news;

    }

    public static ArrayList<BaseElement> getTheater() {

        ArrayList<BaseElement> theaters = new ArrayList<BaseElement>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(
                    CommonService.readJsonUrl(ServiceURL.THEATER_CONTENT.getUrl()));

            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("theater");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                Theater theater = new Theater();

                theater.setTheaterId(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.ID.getTag()));
                theater.setTheaterImage(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.IMAGE.getTag()));
                theater.setName(jsonObj.getString(JSONTag.NAME.getTag()));

                theaters.add(theater);

}

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return theaters;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your LazyAdapter class, in getView() override, add an OnClickListener on the built view, before you return it:

```
view.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            activity.getFragmentManager().beginFragmentTransaction()
            .replace(
                   R.id.your_place_for_the_details_fragment, 
                   new DetailsFragment(item.get(position)))
            .commit();
        }
    });
```

This will provide means for displaying a new fragment after clicking any of the dynamicaly generated views. Remember to build the new Details fragment basing on the JSON information from the item array.

You may consider using Retrofit of Square group, for an easy implementation of REST JSON communication.
http://square.github.io/retrofit/